# Dropbox PHP SDK not working on production server

Tags: php, production-environment, dropbox-php

I am playing around with Dropbox PHP SDK and I have a wired problem. On my localhost environment it works like a charm, but on my server it does not. I have ssl and the dropbox redirect urls is: https://flaviuscojocariu.com/arhitecta/dropbox_finished.php

I don't understand where the problem can be, as I searched my entire code for http://localhost/ links and replaced everything. I get only the 500 error and I don't understand why.

Can someone advice?

If needed I can provide more code. This is the code which I use for auth.

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';


$dropboxKey = '***';
$dropboxSecret = '***';
$appName = '***';

$appInfo = new Dropbox\AppInfo($dropboxKey,$dropboxSecret);

// Store CSRF token

$csrfToken = new Dropbox\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION, 'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');


// Define auth details

$webAuth = new Dropbox\WebAuth($appInfo, $appName, 'http://localhost/arhitecta/dropbox_finished.php', $csrfToken);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=arhitecta;', 'root','');

//User datails

$user = $db->prepare("
     SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :user_id 
");

$user->execute(['user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']]);
$user = $user->fetchObject();
```

Comment: Please expand on what doesn't work. Make sure you are logging all errors on your production server and check the error logs.

Comment: It simply does not redirects to the dropbox for giving the app rights and it only returns 500 error page. here is a link which works on localhost and on the production server is not working https://flaviuscojocariu.com/arhitecta/index.php?path=/ . I am logged in dropbox and errors are on.

Comment: Works now ... was an apache2 error ... the server got stuck and didn't restart properly. :)